# IntelliJ IDEA persistence support for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I try to create a Spring Boot 2 project with JPA to access a MySQL database using Hibernate. I have created a Gradle project on http://start.spring.io/ with JPA and MySQL dependency and imported into IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Ultimate

By default the persistence tool window is not present. I have searched for solution and found many different answer and know I'm a bit confused how should I configure my project. What is the correct way to do it?

1. What framework support should I add to my project?

   - Spring Data JPA
   - Hibernate
   - JPA
2. How should I add them?

   - Right click on my module and "Add Framework Support" (I can select Spring Data JPA and Hibernate here)
   - Project Structure -> Facets -> Add (I can select Hibernate and JPA here)
3. If my project name is db and I have the db_main and db_test modules then to which one should I attach the Facet?

   - db
   - db_main

At the moment I added JPA Facet with Hibernate provider and added the persistence.xml. So I have the Persistence window.

However if I try to generate entities I select the datasource, the tables, the package but nothing happens. I mean no error message just the window closes as if it would be succeeded but there is no changes in the xml and no entity was generated.

Answer (score 26):

After trying a lot of solutions found on the web here is what worked for me. I hope this helps someone.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Ultimate

**Step 1.**

I have created a **Spring Boot** (2.0.0 M5) project using **Gradle** with the built in wizard and select **Web**, **JPA** and **MySQL** dependencies. 
[image]

This gives you a very simple project structure but the **Persistence tool** is not available:
[image]

**Step 2.**

Add **JPA** to Facets in **Project Structure** window to the main module and set **Default JPA Provider** to **Hibernate**.

*Note that no descriptor was added.*

[image]

As result the **Persistence tool** window is now available and it automatically contains **Entities** as Persistence Unit.

[image]

**Step 3.**

In the **Database Tool window**, add new DataSource to your project and also set datasource properties in the application.properties file.

[image]

**Step 4.**

In the Persistence tool window right click on **Entities** and select **Generate Persistence Mapping** and **By Database Schema**

[image]

Now you can select for which tables you want to generate an entity:

[image]

IDEA will generate the entity classes for you.

[image]

**Step 5.**

At this point if you open the **JPA console** and write your HQL or JPL query it will fail. You need to rebuild your project before using the console.

[image]

Comment: This instruction could not be found on Jetbrain helps. Thanks